# how to validate textfield that allows only single decimal point in textfield?

Tags: iphone, ios, validation, uitextfield

I need to restrict user to enter only two digit after decimal point. I have achieved this by following code in  textfield delegate shouldChangeCharactersInRange. But its allowing to enter more than one dot. how to restrict this? Thanks in advance.

```
            NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            if([sep count]>=2)
            {
                NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
                NSLog(@"sepStr:%@",sepStr);

                return !([sepStr length]>2);
            }
            return YES;
```

Comment: please don't forget that different countries use different decimal separators. So just using `.` might not be enough.

Comment: @Gowtham: I just used your code and just put extra two lines.. It's working fine.. Ignore the NSLog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

NSString *sepStr;

NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if([sep count]>=2)
   {
        sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
        NSLog(@"sepStr:%@",sepStr);
        if([sepStr length] >2)
       {
        return NO;
       }
    else 
       {
        return YES;
       }

   }
   return YES;
 }
```

Comment: @Gowtham: I just used your code and just put extra two lines.. It's working fine.. Ignore the NSLog..

Comment: & Nitin I tried the above solution but it didn't work.. Have a make any changes?

Answer (score 12):

The best way is to use `Regular Expression` in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` delegate method like this

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSString *newStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]*)(\\.([0-9]+)?)?$";

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:nil];
    NSUInteger noOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newStr
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [newStr length])];
    if (noOfMatches==0){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

After implementing this valid strings are:
12.004546
4546.5456465
.5464
0.454

So on....

You can also restrict number of integer after decimal by using this `Regular Expression`
`@"^([0-9]*)(\\.([0-9]{0,2})?)?$"`

After implementing this valid strings are:
12.00
4546.54
.54
0.45

Answer (score 2):

When a dot is entered, you should check whether a dot is present already, and return NO if it is present.

```
 NSString * newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: range withString: string];
 NSArray * sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString: @"."];
 if([string isEqualToString:@"."] && [sep count] > 1){
    //already a . is  there.. so don't allow new one
    return NO;
 }
 if ([sep count] >= 2) {
     NSString * sepStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [sep objectAtIndex: 1]];
     NSLog(@"sepStr:%@", sepStr);

     return !([sepStr length] > 2);
 }
 return YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for Swift 3 using the reg ex `"^([0-9]*)(\\.([0-9]+)?)?$"`:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newText = ((textField.text ?? "") as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    let expression = "^([0-9]*)(\\.([0-9]+)?)?$"

    guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: expression, options: .caseInsensitive) else {
        return false
    }
    let noOfMatches = regex.numberOfMatches(in: newText, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, newText.characters.count))

    return noOfMatches > 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     NSRange temprange = [textField.text rangeOfString:@"."];
        if ((temprange.location != NSNotFound) && [string isEqualToString:@"."])
        {
            return NO;
        }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSArray *sep = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if([string isEqualToString:@"."]){
        if([textField.text containsString:@"."]){
            return NO;
        }
    }
    if([sep count] >= 2)
    {
        NSString *sepStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep objectAtIndex:1]];
        return !([sepStr length]>2);
    }
    return YES;
}
```